# How to change error handling policy for GraphQL subscription

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I need to apply "*all*" error policy to a subscription to be able to receive both, errors and data from the server message.
Now if server error occurred, graphql errors are treated as network errors and I'm not able to receive data that was partly gathered from the database.

According to the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/), there is three error policy available and you can easily apply them to [queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/) and [mutations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/). But there are no error policy settings for subscriptions.

Here is how I create subscription:

```
const wsClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: new WebSocketLink({
      uri: "MY_ENDPOINT",
      options: { lazy: true, reconnect: true},
    })
  });
wsClient.subscribe(MY_QUERY)
    .subscribe({
      next: (response: FetchResult) => {
        // assume both response.errors and response.data available here
      },
      error: (err: ApolloError) => {
        // this function is called whenever server responde with errors
      }
    });
```

Is there a way to apply "*all*" policy to graphql subscription or workaround to emulate that behavior?